# Probability of one device among 6 failing

Tags: probability

A certain component of an electronic device has a probability of 0.1 of failing. If there are 6 such components in a circuit. What is the probability that at least one fails?

This is not a duplicate as I want an answer that suits my style of thinking.

My style: How can we solve the problem by calculating the probability that the individual device fails divided by the total probability? I.E. I'm approaching the problem as it were a marble problem where a bag has 2 types of marbles(blue and red); this type of problem asks for the probability of selecting blue marbles if a given amount of x blue marbles exist and y red marbles exist. solution = #blue/#total marbles

Question about an alterantive method: How is the probability that one of these components fail = 1 minus the probability that all succeed?

Comment: "The total probability" is always one.  For a (finite) bag of marbles analogy to work here, you must replace and mix the bag after each draw.

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: In the problem above if the first component ( or any bunch of them ) is bad the other components still have a .1 probability of failure. If in your marble model you pull a blue marble and do not replace it then the probabilities of failure ( number of blue marbles ) has gone down. That is why you replace the marble after each draw. it is still better to treat this as a binomial distribution ( with replacement ) rather than a hypergeometric one ( no replacement ), even though for a large number of marbles they will be close.

Comment: @Ben You can put $1$ blue marble and $9$ red marbles in a bag and say that the probability of drawing the blue marble is the same as the probability that the first device fails. For six devices you can draw six times from the same bag (putting the marble back in after each draw) or you can start with six bags. How does your style of thinking deal with this and what answer do you get? Consider editing the question to explain this further.

Answer (score 0):

Answer about the alternative method: There are total six electronic components. I can divide the whole set of all possible outcomes into seven *disjoint* categories, namely (0) No device fails (1) One device fails (2) Two devices fail (3) . . . .(6) All of the six devices fail. So the event *at least one device fails* is the disjoint union of last *six* events. So you can compute the probability of each such event and add them. Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(\text{at least one device fails})=\sum_{k=1}^{6}\mathbb{P}(\text{$k$ devices fail}).
\end{eqnarray}
However, we know that the total probability is $1$. In other words, $\sum_{k=0}^{6}\mathbb{P}(\text{$k$ devices fail})=1$. Therefore a better approach would be to compute $\mathbb{P}(\text{none of the devices fail})$ and subtract it from $1$. Since the events are independent (I guess), $\mathbb{P}(\text{none of the devices fail})=(0.9)^{6}$. Your answer is $1-(0.9)^{6}$. This problem is an application of the [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: but the questions didn't say that at least one device fails. it says calculate the probability for one device failing. what do you mean by at least one device fails?

Comment: Your question: "A certain component of an electronic device has a probability of 0.1 of failing. If there are 6 such components in a circuit. What is the probability that *at least* one fails?".

Comment: what's the difference between calculate the probability that at least one fails and exactly one fails?

Comment: Roughly speaking *at least one fails* is a bigger event than *exactly* one fails. For example, think about tossing two coins. The possible outcomes are $\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$. *Exactly one tail* corresponds to the outcomes $\{HT,TH\}$, whereas *at least one tail* corresponds to the event $\{HT,TH,TT\}$. Your problem can be thought as tossing six coins, and *occurrence of a tail = failure of a component*